# Dividing the sequnce into a countable number of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We'll say that than a family of sequences $\lbrace(b^\lambda_n)\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ spans the sequences $(a_n)$ if $\forall n: a_n = b^\mu_s$ for exactly one pair $(\mu, s) \in \Lambda \times \mathbb N$.

Let's consider a sequence $(a_n)$. It's not difficult to show that if a finite family of sequences $\lbrace(b^\lambda_n)\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ spans $(a_n)$, and $$\forall \lambda \in \Lambda: \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n^\lambda = g ~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = g ~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2) $$
We even don't need to suppose  *for exactly one pair*, we could say *for some pair* instead.

But what if the family is not finite, but still countable, i.e. $\lvert \Lambda\rvert = \aleph_0$. In this case, does (1) still imply (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another counterexample - even if we split the sequence into $\aleph_0$ disjoint subsequences, the statement is not true.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. 
Let $(x^k)$ be its subsequence of all numbers in form $a_{n^2 + k}$ where $n^2 + k < (n+1)^2$.

We clearly split that our sequence $a_n$ is split into $\aleph_0$ disjoint subsequences. Now if for each $k$ we have $x^k_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then each subsequence $(x^k_n)$ converges to $0$ but the whole sequence $(a_n)$ diverges

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Take $a_n=n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $\Lambda=\Bbb N$, and for $\ell\in\Bbb N$ define the sequence $b^\ell$ by

$$b_n^\ell=\begin{cases}
\ell,&\text{if }n=\ell\\
2^{-n-1},&\text{if }n\ne\ell\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n^\ell=0$ for each $\ell\in\Bbb N$, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a unique pair $\langle \ell,k\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ such that $a_n=b_k^\ell$, namely, $\langle n,n\rangle$. However, $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ clearly diverges.